# To show that $((a,b), b) =(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I have to To show that $((a,b), b) =(a,b)$

Let $d=(a,b)$.
So consider$(d,b)$. Now this means i have to find a greatest common divisor of (greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$,  and $b$. This is equivalent to saying to find gcd of a and b which is d. So i have $(d,b)=d$. Putting value of $d$ to get result back. is this correct ?

Comment: By definition it's a common divisors of (a,b) and of b. As (a,b) is a divisor of a, then any divisor of (a,b) is a divisor of a. So it is a common divisor of both a and b. But (a,b) divides both (a,b) and b so it is at least as big as the *greatest* common divisor.  But it can't be *bigger* than the gcd.  So it is the gced.

Comment: Perhaps it may be more straightforward to prove, if $k|b $ then $\gcd (k,b)=k $.  Then this follows directly.

Comment: @fleablood If $k|b$ then $kx=b$, where $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Consider $(k,kx)$. This is same as saying to find gcd of a number and its multiple which is number itself. So $(k,kx)=k$

Comment: Right.  And since $\gcd (a,b)|b $ does't that mean $\gcd (\gcd (a,b),b)=\gcd (a,b) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: if $k|d $ then $\gcd(k,d)=k $

Pf: $k $ is a common divisor of $k$ and $d$.  If $m>k $ the $m\not \mid k $.  So $k $ is greatest common divisor of $k $ and $d $.

So $\gcd (a,b) $ divides $b $ by definition.  So $\gcd (\gcd (a,b),b)=\gcd (a,b)$.

Or simply note $\gcd((a,b),b) $ that $\gcd (a,b)$ is a common divisor of $\gcd (a,b)$ and $b $.  So $\gcd( (a,b),b)\ge \gcd (a,b) $.  But $\gcd( (a,b),b)$ divides $\gcd (a,b) $ so $\gcd (\gcd (a,b),b)\le \gcd (a,b) $ so $\gcd (\gcd (a,b),b)=\gcd (a,b) $.

Furthermore $\gcd (\gcd(a,b),b) $ divides $\gcd (a,b) $ which divides $a $ so $\gcd (\gcd (a,b),b) $ is a common divisor of $a $ and $b $ so...

Comment: I donot get your answer

Comment: Right on point. typo: $k\nmid k$ you meant $m\nmid k$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=d\, a_1, b=d\, b_1$, $(a_1, b_1)=1$ so  $(a,b)=d.$  Then 
$$
((a,b),b)=(d, b)=(d, d b_1)=d (1,b_1)=d \cdot 1 =d =(a,b).
$$